# javascript files not loading or some other issue?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a basic knockout.js script to run and I'm not sure whether it's the files not loading correctly, or if it's another issue.

Essentially I'm just trying to get a snippet of a tutorial to work on localhost. I'm using PHP which calls the function "names". All it should do is display the names listed in the javascript file. The tutorial can be found [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)

```
//on name_test.php
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="name_test.js"></script>  //name_test.js is in the folder with all of my other files
</head>

//bunch of irrelevant code omitted

<?
function names(){
    ?>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    <?
}
?>
```

Here's the javascript file

```
// name_test.js
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = "first name here";
  this.lastName = "last name here";
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Right now when the page loads all I see is

```
First name:
Last name:
```

Is there something I'm missing here? The javascript file is in the directory with all of my other files. I've also tried the entire path (in xampp) and it still displays nothing.

Comment: If you're just learning KO...why use PHP? I'd suggest starting with flat HTML...

Comment: @ahren It's part of a much larger file. This is being integrated into an existing API. Regardless, that shouldn't affect files being included in the header, would it?

Comment: Have you tried moving your javascript to the bottom of the page?

Comment: The javascript file only contains what is shown

Comment: Yeah I get that, so include your `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, for me it works just fine:

HTML-File:

- Set Script-Tags to bottom
- Removed the PHP-Code

so we have:

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.js">   </script>
<script src="name_test.js"></script>
```

JS-File (unchanged):

```
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = "first name here";
  this.lastName = "last name here";
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

It also works when I use the PHP-Version (of course I call the names() function after declarating it, I assume you forgot that in your example above?)

```
<?php
function names(){
    ?>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    <?php
}
names();
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="name_test.js"></script>
```

I'm sorry I can't help you any further, but it works for me. And I am not using any libraries, just your script-tags.

Comment: I'm almost now positive it's something to do with the way my API is loading the files. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1123815: Then I would suggest to debug it "the hard way". Start with a flat HTML-File that works and incrementally add complexity until it breaks. Thats all I can say without knowing more about your API and about the way this files are loaded and handled.

Answer (score 2):

`<script>` tags are executed at the time they are parsed.  At the time your `applyBindings()` function runs, the DOM is not yet loaded. You need to run it after the DOM has loaded (at the bottom of the script), or by running it in `window.onload` or something like jQuery `$(document).ready()`.

```
// name_test.js
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = "first name here";
  this.lastName = "last name here";
}

// Run after the window has loaded    
window.onload = function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel())
};

// Or if you are using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel())
});
```

This is documented in the [Knockout observables documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Finally, you could also just move the `<script src='name_test.js></script>` to the end of the document, and it will load at the time it is parsed, which is after the rest of the DOM has parsed.

Comment: @user1123815 Which did you try? I have 3 options above.

Comment: I didn't notice that you have wrapped the content in a PHP function.  Remove that function, or call it as the answer below notes.

Comment: Failing that, always develop JavaScript with your browser's console open. Any errors will appear there.

Comment: I put my ViewModel logic in a separate file, but always have the "ko.applyBindings" statement in the HTML file for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hi there, you missed the `http://`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, that is called a protocol-relative URL and is valid.  Starting with `//` allows it to work for http or https (or any other protocol) according to the protocol of the parent script